# VK API. Метод wall.get. Что означают различные параметры поля album_id?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Метод `wall.get` возвращает для каждой картинки среди прочих поле `album_id`, которое может принимать различные значения. Я выбрал несколько разных со своей стены. С 9-тизначным числом понятно - это `id` одного из моих альбомов, куда было добавлено фото перед отправкой на стену. А что означают остальные числа? В официальной документации к этому методу описания возвращаемых полей я не нашёл.

```
[album_id] => 220000000
[album_id] => -7
[album_id] => -2
[album_id] => -24
[album_id] => 2
[album_id] => -5
```

**Обновление**

Пока удалось выяснить, что значение `-24` соответствует картинкам, добавленным на стену как граффити. С остальными не очень понятно. Статус `-7`, например, имеют картинки добавленные мной сразу на стену, т.е. не из существующего уже альбома (такие вроде бы сохраняются в альбом "Фотографии на моей стене"), и картинки из репостов других пользователей.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно описанию объекта [photo](https://vk.com/dev/photo), то это просто такой id: `album_id – идентификатор альбома, в котором находится фотография.`

Взял id юзера из `wall.get` и `album_id=-6` и вернулась инфа о альбоме:

```
https://vk.com/dev/photos.getAlbums?params[owner_id]=1&params[album_ids]=-6&params[need_system]=0&params[need_covers]=0&params[photo_sizes]=0&params[v]=5.45
```

Comment: Спасибо! Не догадался посмотреть этот метод. Теперь понятно, что  знак минус перед `id` имеют системные альбомы конкретного юзера или сообщества.